# How can I save directly from .csv file to SQLyog using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, csv

This is my usual code which is from textboxes.

```
con.execute("INSERT INTO `tablename` (`Column1`, `Column2`) VALUES ('"& textbox1.text &"', '"& textbox2.text &"')")
```

The thing is I don't know how to do it from .csv file, that will insert to SQLyog without anything toolbox use, just save it directly to the code and a messagebox for confirmation. Can you help me guys?. Thank you.

Comment: SQLyog is not a database - it is a UI front end for a database which has a very powerful import mechanism

Comment: @Plutonix sorry for considering that its a database, anyway can you help me on how can i save my csv file to database. (answer is appreciated.) Thank you.